# Error when publishing an ASP.NET Website with "Enable Organizational Authentication" selected

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have created a basic ASP.NET website using "Organizational Accounts" as the authentication mechanism.

It works perfectly well running on localhost.

However when I attempt to publish it to Azure with the "Enable Organizational Authentication" option enabled I get the following error box.

"*Provisioning the destination end point failed with the error:
'Unable to configure Organization Authentication for this project.  Please try later'
If you don't intent to enable Orgnizational Authentication during publish, please turn that option off in the publish dialog
"*

I get this error regardless of whether I try to use a "Microsoft Account" to publish the site or a Azure AD account that is has global administration rights and co-admin rights to the Azure subscription.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 2):

I think what is happening is the credentials for Azure Directory are getting lost.  There doesn't seem to be a way to directly enter the correct credentials.

Inside the Publish Web settings change the domain under File Publish Options. Try to publish and then set it back.  It will ask you for credentials, enter for the Global Administrator.  It should work then.

Comment: ... you were right.  What was happening was VS.NET was getting itself mixed up with my "Organisational" and "Microsoft" Accounts.  Making sure you are logged in with the correct account type at the correct time in the deployment process is very important.

Comment: It looks like the issue is resolved in VS 2013, update 3, [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/use-a-microsoft-account-to-create-web-apps-protected-by-azure-ad-with-vs2013-update-3.aspx).